# How can I make a user registration form using a model which extends a base user model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm familiar with Python, but not much with Django. My first instinct was to use the `__init__()` and `super()` methods to allow a form class to inherit another, but then I came to the thought that maybe this isn't possible, as I haven't seen anything of the sort in Django's documentation.

My models are as follows:

```py
models.py

class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, full_name, password=None):
        user = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username,
            full_name = full_name,
        )

        # the superuser method is also present, it has the same fields, but is cut for readability
        return user

class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser):
    # basic information fields such as username, email, etc.
    # also is the model which has the permissions, USERNAME_FIELD, and REQUIRED_FIELDS

class BuyerAccount(models.Model):
    # extension of the base user, which will have additional information if needed
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shipping_address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    billing_address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username # the admin panel will return an error if I leave it at self.user
```

The models work as expected and there is no issue with them. I can view, add, and edit them as necessary. However, when I went to give them custom views, I ran into some issues.

```py
admin.py

class AccountAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'full_name', 'date_joined', 'last_login', 'is_admin')
    search_fields = ('username', 'email', 'full_name')
    readonly_fields = ('date_joined', 'last_login')
    
    filter_horizontal = ()
    list_filter = ()
    fieldsets = ()

class BuyerAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ['user', 'shipping_address', 'billing_address']
    search_fields = ['user']
    readonly_fields = []
    ordering = ('user',)

    filter_horizontal=[]
    list_filter=[]
    fieldsets = ()
```

This is fine when displaying them on the admin console. It shows the proper rows, and the user with which it's connected. The issue arises when I go to add an entry for the BuyerAccount, giving me the following error: `type object 'BuyerAccount' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'`. I suspected that this is caused by not having the proper registration form, and this is where I ran into the wall.

Here is the `forms.py`:

```py
class BaseUserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=250, required=True)
    full_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
    phone = forms.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = UserAccount
        fields = ("username", "email", "full_name", "phone", "password1", "password2")

class BuyerRegistrationForm(BaseUserRegistrationForm):
    pass
```

I'm not experienced enough with Django to know how to do this. Usually in a database you'd open up a transaction, put one after the other and call it a day. Here, since the Buyer user is an extension of the base (custom) User, I thought I could somehow make the Buyer form using inheritance, but even thinking of a solution is proving difficult.

If complete refactoring and remaking of the models is necessary, I will do it, I would like to learn the proper practices of Django.

Answer (score 0):

In Django, when you have a custom user model and you want to create a related model (like `BuyerAccount` in your case) that extends the base user model, you don't typically inherit from the user model's form classes (`UserCreationForm`, etc.). Instead, you usually create a separate form for your related model and link it to the base user model using a foreign key.

Here's how you can refactor your models and forms to achieve your goal:

1. **Models**:

You can keep your `UserAccount` model as it is since it serves as the base user model.

models.py:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    # Your manager methods here

class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser):
    # Your UserAccount fields here

class BuyerAccount(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shipping_address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    billing_address = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

2. **Forms**:

You can create a separate form for the `BuyerAccount` model.

forms.py:

```py
from django import forms
from .models import BuyerAccount

class BuyerRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BuyerAccount
        fields = ["shipping_address", "billing_address"]
```

3. **Admin**:

In your admin, you can use `InlineModelAdmin` to manage the `BuyerAccount` related to a `UserAccount`. This way, when you edit a user in the admin panel, you can also add or edit their associated `BuyerAccount`.

admin.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import UserAccount, BuyerAccount
from .forms import BuyerRegistrationForm

class BuyerInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = BuyerAccount
    form = BuyerRegistrationForm

class AccountAdmin(UserAdmin):
    # Your UserAdmin configurations here

admin.site.unregister(UserAccount)  # Unregister the default UserAdmin
admin.site.register(UserAccount, AccountAdmin)

class BuyerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BuyerRegistrationForm

admin.site.register(BuyerAccount, BuyerAdmin)
```

With these changes, you'll be able to manage `UserAccount` and its associated `BuyerAccount` in the Django admin panel separately. The `BuyerRegistrationForm` allows you to add or edit `BuyerAccount` instances when editing a `UserAccount` in the admin panel.

Here are some additional things to keep in mind:

- When you create a separate form for your related model, you need to
  make sure that the form has a user field that is a foreign key to the
  UserAccount model. This will allow you to associate the BuyerAccount
  with a specific UserAccount instance.
- In your admin, you need to use the InlineModelAdmin class to register
  the BuyerAccount model as an inline model for the UserAccount model.
  This will allow you to manage the BuyerAccount instances in the admin
  panel when you are editing a UserAccount instance.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and searched through some other answers, some that would offer more information, and it turns out I could skip these shenanigans by using `inlineformset_factory()`. Simple, clean, and easy solution when inheritance and extensions are used.

Perhaps I should've searched through the documentation more, since it also covers the issue of how I would display this in a fillable form.
[Here's the documentation for that.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)

In other words, I reformatted my `forms.py` to:

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory
from .models import UserAccount, BuyerAccount

class BaseUserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=250, required=True)
    full_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
    phone = forms.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = UserAccount
        fields = ("username", "email", "full_name", "phone", "password1", "password2")

BuyerRegistrationFormSet = inlineformset_factory(UserAccount, BuyerAccount, fields=('shipping_address', 'billing_address',))
```

Everything else will be updated according to the documentation. No headache, no custom hacky solutions, everything works out of the box.